# Javascript: OS-depending Redirects doesn't work for IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, redirect

i've got a pretty simple Javascript for redirecting a specific URL to an app in  Google-Play-Store/iOS-Store or show an URL for desktop users depending on the client's opersting system. For the ios case the redirect is not being executed, can anyone explain what the problem is? (alert before redirect is being executed properly!)

```
var playStoreUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xyz",
appStoreUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/gxyz/id123456789?mt=8",
desktopUrl = "http://www.xyz.de/apps/";

var isMobile = {
Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
},
iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
 }
};

if ( isMobile.Android() ) {
 alert('os: android!');
 window.location.href = playStoreUrl;
}
else if(isMobile.iOS()) {
 alert('os: ios!');
 window.location.href = appStoreUrl;
}
else {
 alert('os: desktop!');
 window.location.href = desktopUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: don't use the "?mt=8" parameter in the iOS-Appstore-Link and the redirect will work (and open the Appstore-App on your device)